# AWS ECS Fargate multi container interaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have a problem regarding the interaction between containers in a AWS ECS cluster.

I'll start by introducing my project and AWS configuration. My app is split in 2 components: frontend and backend. The frontend runs on port 3000 and the backend runs on port 8000. From the frontend I make some API calls with the usual localhost:8000 which works just in fine on my local machine.

Then I made them into docker images and deployed them to AWS ECR. From there I can't figure it out how to make them communicate. I can first deploy the backend, see the public or private ip and modify the frontend project and change localhost:8000 to 192.... and that works too but it's not the solution that I want.

I couldn't find any tutorial on this and I'm in dire need of help/

Thank you for your time!

What I had in mind it's the following: I have a VPC(192.168.0.0/24) with 4 subnets, 2 public, 2 private. I want to deploy the backend service(or services in the future) on the 2 private without a public IP(which I succeded creating some endpoints in the VPC). Then I want to have the frontend service(or services) still on the 2 private networks but with a public IP to access it.

I discovered 2 possibilities: with an option when creating an AWS ECS service "Service Connect" and using an Load Balancer. But I didn't succeded on using them. I tried in special the "Service Connect" option.
I created a namespace named "ECS" and in that I created a service named "my-backend". From there I see that I can register a service instance but I need to provide an ID which I saw that need to match with the backend task ID and fill out the IP address on the private subnet with the port. I'm blocked at this step.. this means that I have to register a instance every time a new task of a backend runs? and in the frontend i need to replace the url to the backend with http://my-backend.ECS:8000?

Update 1

The frontend is using React and the requests are running on the users browser.

The frontend and backend are running of separate services and separate tasks.

Comment: Please clarify your configuration: Is your front-end code a JavaScript app using something like Angular/React/Vue? Specifically, are the requests to the backend actually coming from the code running in the user's web browser, or from a front-end server? Also, I assume you are running the front-end and back-end servers as separate services in ECS, with separate task definitions?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I updated the question to answer your questions.

Comment: Your clarification on the front end doesn't make sense. If it is a React app, then the front-end server is just serving static files to the web browser, and the front-end code is actually running in the web browser. In that scenario, your API calls to the backend are actually coming from each user's web browser (the user's laptop/desktop computers) not the front-end server. For that to work you have to make the backend server publicly available on the Internet.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed the edit to match it. That means that I can't use any other solution to leave the backend servers in the private subnet? I hoped that there is something like using the public  ip address of the frontend and if it's for port 8000 to redirect the traffic to the backend servers using something like a ALB.

Comment: You almost certainly need to use an ALB to expose your servers to the Internet. You can do exactly what you just described in your comment using an ALB.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response, how could I use a single address for the backend servers that for frontend use in their bakcend-url to redistrube traffic to a target group of backend using and ALB?

Comment: You would use the URL of the load balancer. That's the whole point of the load balancer. You use the single address of the load balancer to send traffic, and the load balancer distributes that traffic across the targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the replies, my suggestion is keep the front end service in the private subnets as well and don't assign it a public ip. Use an ALB to receive all public traffic, and associate the front end ecs service with this load balancer (along with a target group and listener, and security group rule to allow the ALB/target group to reach the front end service). Place the front end service and all of the backend services in the same service connect namespace. In the task definitions, set the portMappings. For simplicity I would give the port name the same name as the service itself, and containerPort and hostPort to the same port as what the service in the container listens on.

```
      portMappings = [
        {
          name          = service-name
          containerPort = service-port
          hostPort      = service-port
          protocol      = "tcp"
          appProtocol   = "http"
        }
      ]
```

Then in your front end service, call your backend services via `http://service-name:service-port`. Backend services can talk to each other the same way as well

browser -> ALB -> target group -> front end service, calls to backend services via `http://some-backend-service:some-backend-port`, `http://some-other-backend-service:some-other-backend-port`, etc), which will get routed to -> the backend service(s).

for things to communicate with each other, on top of Service Connect, you may need to attach a security group that allows traffic to/from itself and attach it to all of the services.